# Pseudoelement with position: fixed not working in tag <button> in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, button, css-position

I have a problem. In Firefox - Pseudo element with position: fixed in tag button not cover that button.

Example

```
<button class='test'>lalal</button>

.test {
    position: relative;
}
.test::after {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xt9eLb8z/4/

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `position:fixed` use `position:absolute`.

With `position:fixed` the element is related to and sized with the **viewport** and not the parent element.

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport, except when one of its ancestors has a transform, perspective, or filter property set to something other than none (see the CSS Transforms Spec), in which case that ancestor behaves as the containing block. (Note that there are browser inconsistencies with perspective and filter contributing to containing block formation.) Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.
>
> <sup>[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)</sup>

```css
.test::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

.test {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<button class='test'>lalal</button>
```

Comment: But in my case I should have pseudo element over all blocks (e.x. background to pop-up). Therefore I have to use position: fixed.

Comment: Why are you using a pseudo-element for this. It's not clear what you are trying to do.